# populating html table from database

Tags: java, jsp

I want to generate html table in my jsp witch display values selected before submitting to allow user to know what did he puts into the form.

So I finish the form when submitting the values are inserted in database.
Now I search the possibility to display in the same jsp of the form the table having all the values selected.
So it is possible ton allow to actions in the form tag to insert and display from database at the same time.

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you asking whether it's possible to display a table in a form that, as the user edits the cells, the corresponding database entries are updated (perhaps when the user moves away from a cell, presses Enter or hits a Submit button) without having to refresh the whole web page? Do you just want to display a confirmation page showing the values before the user hits a Commit button and gets them written away to the database?

Comment: yes, I want to show values already inserted in database when submitting the form in a simple html table taht i can next time modified it (delete a cell).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is doable. If you'd like to reuse input elements, just redisplay the value in their `value` attributes. E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(bean.foo)}" />
```

The JSTL [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) is by the way there to prevent [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

If you'd rather like to display them plain text, then you can use JSTL [`c:if`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html) or [`c:choose`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/choose.html) to render HTML conditionally. E.g.

```
<c:if test="${editmode}">
    <input type="text" name="foo" />
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!editmode}">
    ${fn:escapeXml(bean.foo)}
</c:if>
```

Here `editmode` is of course a `boolean` representing the edit mode.